# Adding page breaks to tables in PDF templates for NETSuite

Tags: templates, netsuite, bfo

On page 176/177 of the [SuiteBuilder Customisation Guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjmuerP7ObbAhXLOcAKHR3uAsIQFgg1MAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fcloud%2Flatest%2Fnetsuitecs_gs%2FNSBLD%2FNSBLD.pdf&usg=AOvVaw078KOKrV929dyq54eUIXbK), Oracle explain how it's possible to add page breaks to tables within a template.

The example given is:

```
<!-- start of item table in transaction -->
<#list record.item as item>
    <#if item_index==0> <!-- Header Definition -->
        <tr>
            <th>${item.field1@label}</th>
            <th>${item.long_text_field@label}</th>
            <th>${item.field2@label}</th>
            <!-- ... -->
        </tr>
    </#if>
    <#list item.long_text_field?split("<br />") as paragraph>
        <#if desc_index==0>
            <tr>
                <td>${item.field1}</td>
                <td>${paragraph}</td>
                <td>${item.field2}</td>
                <!-- ... -->
            </tr>
        <#else>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>${paragraph}</td>
                <td></td>
                <!-- ... -->
            </tr>
        </#if>
    </#list>
</#list>
<!-- end of item table in transaction -->
```

However this is resulting in the following error:

[image]

It appears that the term `desc_index` is unable to be evaluated, and furthermore, the term does not appear an any other NETSuite related documentation other than here.

Is this a bug/typo/deprecated code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typo in the example.

List indexes in Freemarker are referenced by concatenating the list name with "_index".  So, in this example, `desc_index` should be replaced with `paragraph_index`.

It appears they adapted this example from another snippet with a list name of 'desc' (probably for 'description') but neglected to update the index reference to match.

Of course, you need to change `long_text_field`, `field1` and `field2` to real fields that are available to the template for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing the title of your question...

You can add actual page breaks using the `<pbr>` tag. You can also set a new page layout. Please see the BFO documentation for more info. However, you probably do not want to use this to break apart a table directly unless you have logic to close and recreate the continuation of the table data.
https://bfo.com/products/pdf/docs/userguide.pdf

When slicing up a table, you want to use CSS like `page-break-inside: avoid;`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside

Comment: BFO Tag Reference Here: https://bfo.com/products/report/docs/tags/